# Não consigo compilar meu projeto Flutter VS Code Dart/ null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

- A MSG DE ERRO È ESSA

```
'Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

 - package:webview_flutter
 - package:url_launcher_web
 - package:url_launcher_platform_interface
 - package:plugin_platform_interface
2

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety
Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Unsupported Null Safety mode NonNullableByDefaultCompiledMode.Invalid, in null.
#0      ProgramCompiler.emitModule (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:472:9)
#1      JavaScriptBundler.compile (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/src/javascript_bundle.dart:153:33)
#2      FrontendCompiler.writeJavascriptBundle (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/frontend_server.dart:694:47)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/frontend_server.dart:602:9)
###############################################################
```

- Meu Código é esse

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Unidos em Um',
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
                child: WebView(
                  initialUrl: 'https://unidosemum.com/',
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                ))));
  }
}
```

Comment: Rode com a opção [`--no-sound-null-safety`](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety)

Answer (score -2):

É interessante estar postando o log do seu console executando o comando `flutter doctor` junto do problema.

Seu erro diz que você está tentando usar packages que não suportam null-safety.

Você pode estar acrescentando a flag --no-sound-null-safety para tentar driblar isto momentaneamente:

```
flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
```

Conheço alguns desses packages e acredito que se você subir a versão deles (url_launcher por exemplo) ele ja entre em null-safety.

Para saber mais sobre o null safety tem um post muito legal no Medium:

[Dart - Announcing sound null safety](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-sound-null-safety-defd2216a6f3)

edit: Ou pode estar descendo a versão de seu dart também!

Comment: Conferi os links, agradeço pela orientação Augusto, vou seguir.